# So why does Canon 5D Mark II have a better video quality than Canon 60D?

Tags: canon, video, canon-60d, canon-5d-mark-ii, hd-video

Assuming that Canon 5D Mark II and Canon 60D both have the same processor, DIGIC 4 (single), why does the former shoots a better quality video? *Better quality* I mean the technical aspect, the video/compression itself.

Let's ignore the visual aspect like more shallow depth of field, for example.

I know 5D is a full-frame, but the video is 1920px wide. The 60D shoots 18MPx, which scaled down to 1920px wide should still look almost the same as if shot on full-frame initially, right?

Therefore, and this is my point:

```
UNCOMPRESSED INPUT -> DIGIC 4 -> OUTPUTTED VIDEO
```

If we exclude the depth of field and a better ISO handling from our equation, it's possible that the uncompressed input is the same on both cameras, right? Then, it goes to the digic 4 processor to be compressed, which is the same on both cameras. Yet, we end up with a better quality video on one of those cammeras. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 5D Mk2 has a far larger sensor (because it's a full frame camera) and more pixels. My assumption would be the camera scales down the input to 1920x1080 so having more uncompressed data allows it to give a higher quality output.

If Andres's comment about it skipping lines whilst taking video is right, then the improvement in quality is more likely down solely to its lower pixel density. A lower pixel density means a bigger area per pixel, which means more light per pixel, more light per pixel means less amplification is required (amplification increases noise also)

Comment: Quality is related to surface area, not linear size. So while the diagonal *is 1/3 larger* the surface area is 2.25X bigger. Otherwise, the full-frame advantage would be much less.

Comment: While the GH2 with its smaller sensor beats them both, save of course depth of field control.

Comment: Right you are @Itai, I'll update my answer

Comment: Are you sure that the camera scales down the video? I thought the HD resolution was achieved by skipping lines.

Comment: @Andres, that was my assumption (as I said in my answer). If you read that somewhere I'd be interested to read it and update my answer!

Comment: I believe @Itai has it nailed. The 5DII has considerably more surface area, which provides a lot more information to interpolate when scaling down to final output size. I would be doubtful that sensor pixel rows are skipped...however I wouldn't be surprised if sRAW-style YCC encoding was used rather than normal bayer interpolation (which uses more bayer pixel data per pixel, and does not overlap pixel interpolation.)

Comment: This article: http://blog.planet5d.com/2011/10/dan-chungs-first-hands-on-preview-of-the-canon-eos-1d-x/
Seems to suggest that line skipping did occur in older DSLRs